# get attribute cant be used on an entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I am trying to make a Jenga Scorer and I am just making a players list. When making this, I stumbled upon that I can't get an attribute from an Entry.

The qadd is the function that does this.
Code:

```
from tkinter import *

players = []

def questionw():
    def addplayer():
        player = qentry.get()
        players.append(player)

    question = Tk()

    question.geometry("200x150")
    qentry = Entry(question,).place(y=60, x=3, width=195, height=20)
    qlabel = Label(question, text="What is the name\nof the player?", justify=CENTER, font=("Amasis MT Pro",12)).pack()
    qdone = Button(question, text="Done").place(y=90, x=10, width=80)
    qadd = Button(question, text=f"Add ({len(players)})", command=addplayer).place(y=90, x=100, width=80)
    qdone = Button(question, text="Cancel").place(y=120, x=55, width=80)

    question.mainloop()

question()
```

When I type something in Add button, it returns this on the console:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\jenga.py", line 5, in addplayer
    player=qentry.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1):

The traceback is telling you that `qentry` is not currently an `Entry`, it is `None`. Also, you are assigning `qentry` the return value of the `place()` method, not the initializer of `Entry`.

Try this:

```
qentry = Entry(question,)
qentry.place(y=60, x=3, width=195, height=20)
```